# Debian: preseed partitioning results in deadlock

Tags: debian, lvm, preseed

I'm using this code in my preseed.cfg for debian testing (wheezy):

```
#Partman
partman-auto partman-auto/init_automatically_partition select 50some_device__________regular
partman-auto partman-auto/select_disk select /var/lib/partman/devices/=dev=sda
partman-auto partman-auto/choose_recipe select /lib/partman/recipes/30atomic
partman-base partman/choose_partition select 90finish__________finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
```

in order to partition entire disk sda with boot+swap+root partition (the "standard" partition whole disk with one partition for everything). However, using this block makes d-i loop endlessly. With DEBCONF_DEBUG=5 I can see on 4th console that it loops around in partman. How do I fix this code, and will adding

```
partman-auto-lvm       partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name    string  in0
partman-auto   partman-auto/init_automatically_partition       select  70some_device_crypto__________crypto
```

(the latter instead of the 1st line of the 1st block) make me a LVM encrypted volume?